# How to create multiple indexes based on conduction in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, filebeat, logstash-file

**Trying to create multiple indexes for elasticsearch in logstash. But my "if conduction" is not creating any single index, without if conduction it is working fine.**

But if I'm using input as file and in logstash without using filebeat then it is working as per my expectation. Can anyone help me for resolution.

```
###filebeat.yml###
=============
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /home/user/vinit/pache/*.log
  fields:
    log_type: apache-log

- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /home/user/vinit/boss/*.log
  fields:
    log_type: jboss-log
  fields_under_root: true

###pipeline-conf.conf###
==================

input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
    grok {
           match => { "message" => "^%{IP:CLIENT_IP} (?:-|%{USER:IDEN}) (?:-|%{USER:AUTH}) \[%{HTTPDATE:CREATED_ON}\] \"(?:%{WORD:REQUEST_METHOD} (?:/|%{NOTSPACE:REQUEST})(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:HTTP_VERSION})?|-)\" %{NUMBER:RESPONSE_CODE} (?:-|%{WORD:BYTES}) (?:-|%{WORD:EXECUTION_TIME})"}
    add_field => {
                "LOG_TYPE" => "api-log"
        }
    overwrite => [ "message" ]
    }
    grok {
           match => { "message" => "%{HTTPDATE:CREATED_ON}%{NOTSPACE}%{SPACE} (?:-|%{IP:CLIENT_IP})%{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE}(?:-|%{WORD:REQUEST_METHOD}%{SPACE}) (?:-|%{NOTSPACE:REQUEST})(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:HTTP_VERSION})%{NOTSPACE}(?:-|%{GREEDYDATA:OTHER_INFO}) (?:-|%{NUMBER:RESPONSE_CODE}) (?:-|%{WORD:BYTES}) (?:-|%{WORD:EXECUTION_TIME})"}
    add_field => {
                "LOG_TYPE" => "web-log"
        }
    overwrite => [ "message" ]
    }
    grok {
           match => { "message" => "%{TIME:CREATED_ON}%{SPACE}\[(?<THREAD>[^\]]+)?\] %{WORD:METHOD}%{SPACE}%{JAVACLASS:CLASS} - (?<MESSAGE_LOG>[^\r\n]+)((\r?\n)(?<extra>(.|\r?\n)+))?"}
    add_field => {
                "LOG_TYPE" => "jboss-log"
        }
    overwrite => [ "message" ]
    }
}
output {
   if [fields][log_type] == "apache-log"{
     elasticsearch {
     hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
     manage_template => false
     index => "server-logs-apache"
     }
  }
   if [fields][log_type] == "jboss-log" {
     elasticsearch {
     hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
     manage_template => false
     index => "server-logs-jboss"
     }
  }
   stdout { codec => rubydebug }    
}

##Also Tried##
==============
output {
       if "apache-log" in [fields][log_type] {
         elasticsearch {
         hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
         manage_template => false
         index => "server-logs-apache"
         }
      }
       if "jboss-log" in [fields][log_type] {
         elasticsearch {
         hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
         manage_template => false
         index => "server-logs-jboss"
         }
      }
       stdout { codec => rubydebug }    
    }
```

**I'm expecting result as indexes : server-logs-apache, server-logs-jboss but actual output is empty.**

Comment: i don't see apache-log in your config, only web-log, api-log, jboss-log

Comment: @Mysterion I'm not using default Apache-log pattern I am using custom log pattern and it's working. But I'm not able to understand that how to use filebeat fields in logstash conduction.

Comment: No, I mean in your data you have field name api-log not apache log as you check later

Comment: Correct! These api-log and web-log are apache logs.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding field which is capital case

```
add_field => { "LOG_TYPE" => "web-log" }
```

and Elasticsearch separates field written with different case. You should add field lowercased - "log_type"

Comment: I changed it to custom_type and it's just a static value. Help to use filebeat variable in logstash.

Comment: I had 3 conf files of logstash i.e first-input.conf, second-filter.conf, third-output.conf. I created one file and combine these three conf files configurations in beat-data.conf file. And now it's working as I want.